# How to scale an UIImage without stretch?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, scale, image-resizing

Greetings of the Day everyone!!

`How to scale an UIImage without stretch?`

I have tried lots of way to achieve this and did follow many SO links, but none of them did work of me. Everywhere there is a solution to resize an image from bigger size to smaller size, but what if I `want to resize an image from bigger to smaller, without losing quality`?

Please take a look at thesse 2 images

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Use higher resolution images?

Comment: how to use high resolution image? I'm picking image from native photo gallery

Comment: It's not possible to make an image larger (as per your screenshots of before and after) without sacrificing image quality. There is only so much information in the image and after you scale it up it will always look worse. Unless you have really high resolution images.

Comment: Let me know if any other solution for this. I really need an urgent solution

Comment: Of course there is no other solution, you are expecting to enlarge (zoom on) an image and not lose quality, you expect to keep the same fidelity? - There is no solution to this. In fact what you are asking about is parodied regularly, because Film and TV often pretend like what you are trying to do is possible, for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhF_56SxrGk

Comment: hmm, so I guess there is another solution to achieve this, crop and then scale image !!! ??